# Google Maps - Full screen on change event?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, events, fullscreen

I've been googling around and I can't find a solution for this problem anywhere. Is there anyway to detect when the map goes full screen or exits full screen? (pretty much like the DOM event onfullscreenchange)

I have a map with the option "fullscreenControl" set to true and all I want to do is center the map on the markers when the map goes fullscreen, as well as displaying an infowindow ONLY when the map is in fullscreen. How can I check for fullscreen changes?

I've tried using DOM events on the whole map but that doesn't seem to work, something like:

```
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), "fullscreen", function () {
            console.log("FULLSCREEN CHANGED");
        });
```

I've also thought that I can make a Custom Control, in place of the X button that is the fullscreenControl, to toggle when the map goes fullscreen and then I can listen for a click event on that custom control, but is there no better way? Is there really no onfullscreenchange event or anything like that?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm updating the answer to include a check using a timer on center_change

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(map,'center_change', updateMapBounds);
}
function updateMapBounds(){
    clearTimeout(mapBoundsTimer);
    mapBoundsTimer = setTimeout(function() {
      updateBounds();
   }, 500);
 }
function updateBounds(){
   //code to get map_div or gm_style class size and compare it to the
   if($('.gm_style').height()===window.innnerHeight &&
      $('.gm_style).width() === window.innerWidth){
      //fit_markers
   }
}
```

But I think you can remove updateMapBounds if you use google.maps.event.addListener(map.'idle',updateBounds());

Comment: Hum I don't need to trigger a resize on the map because the map is a globally accessible variable, but I understand why you suggested to trigger a resize (this way I can capture it and do what I want). About detecting the fullscreen, how do I make the width/height check? Does a "change" listener on the map-canvas work?

Comment: Yes it would, you would then compare it to the height and width to see if it's full sized.

Comment: Okay so I was testing it out a bit further, and apparently there is no easy way to check for changes on the map because it doesn't behave as normal DOM elements. So what I end up doing was to add a listener on the map for when the center changes and then use JQuery to compare the div that Google Maps adds to make the map (it always has a class called "gm-style") height and width with the window's innerHeight and innerWidth, only then do I adjust the bounds. This combined with a flag variable allows me to call fitBounds only once. Does this make sense? Do you wanna update your answer with this?

Comment: I think listening to the idle event will work better, as idle will only get fired after a small amount of time passed.  I believe you might get a series of center_change events depending upon your implementation.  In that case you can put a setTimeout event on the center_change event.  In my case I keep track of the map div and look at the center, height and width to do adjustments to some information that I've put on the map, though gm_style class will give you the height and width as well.  I will update the answer.

Comment: Oh I just realized I didn't explain my problem in detail enough. Your answer is correct (both the updated one and the comment), it's just that in my problem I needed to trigger the fitbounds only once when the map went fullscreen so I could center the view on the markers (because if you drag the map around open in fullscreen you will be nowhere near the markers). Another problem I had was I wanted to open a custom control window on the left side of the map if it's fullscreen so I need to do constant checks on whether it's fullscreen or not to know when to toggle the custom control.

Comment: Because I needed to do constant checks to see whether we are fullscreen or not that's why I decided to use center_changed. But your answer is right regardless, thank you so much!